# React router v6 and URL Params with special characters

Tags: reactjs

I'm reading a url param like:

```
http://localhost:5173/reset-password/abcdef
```

where `abcdef` is a param and works as expected, but when the param includes a point '.' it is not working. example:

```
http://localhost:5173/reset-password/abc.deff
```

It is just not working, I added a wildcard on my router but still not working, This is my router:

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ProfilePage from "../pages/ProfilePage";
import HintsPage from "../pages/HintsPage";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import SignInPage from "../pages/SignInPage";
import SignUpPage from "../pages/SignUpPage";
import ErrorPage from "./ErrorPage";
import PrivateLayout from "./PrivateLayout";
import Settings from "../pages/Settings";
import PublicProfilePage from "../pages/PublicProfilePage";
import HintPage from "../pages/HintPage";
import ProfileLayout from "./ProfileLayout";
import LogoutPage from "../pages/LogoutPage";
import ProfileEditPage from "../pages/ProfileEditPage";
import ForgotPasswordPage from "../pages/ForgotPasswordPage";
import ResetPasswordPage from "../pages/ResetPasswordPage";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Layout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <SignInPage /> },
      { path: 'signin', element: <SignInPage /> },
      { path: 'signup', element: <SignUpPage /> },
      { path: 'box/:boxId', element: <PublicProfilePage /> },
      { path: 'logout', element: <LogoutPage /> },
      { path: 'forgot-password', element: <ForgotPasswordPage /> },
      { path: 'reset-password/:recoveryToken*', element: <ResetPasswordPage /> },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <PrivateLayout />,
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'profile', 
        element: <ProfileLayout />,
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <ProfilePage /> },
          { path: 'hints/:knowId', element: <HintsPage /> },
        ]
      },
      { path: 'profile-edit', element: <ProfileEditPage /> },
      { path: 'settings', element: <Settings /> },
      { path: 'hint/:knowId', element: <HintPage /> },
    ]
  }
])

export default router
```

Any help will be great!

Comment: What do you mean by _"not working"_? Does it route to your `ResetPasswordPage` component? Is the param value incorrect and if so, how?

Comment: As per [this comment](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8699#issuecomment-1369903743), _dynamic parameters (`:param`) [with special characters] are required to be full url segments_.

Comment: @Phil not working = "this localhost page can't be found"

Comment: I cannot reproduce any such issue ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-wu-87rzj9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: anyway react router v6 doesn't support regex so the wildcard is wrong.